# JQuery mobile: Running a code after page refreshes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I want to run below code, but I have another peace of code that runs and refreshes a list every time you click on the icon of that page. The below code is working well, but then is overwritten by the refresh and the result disappears after seconds. I have read many related question but unfortunately with very inconsistent answers.

This is the code I want to run after the page with the `id=page-activity` is refreshed. Any tips?

```
function ShowList(){
var m = $("#flip-1").val() == "on";
var f = $("#flip-2").val() == "on";
$('#myListView li').show();
if (m && !f) {
    $("#myListView li:contains('female')").hide();
} else if (!m && f) {
    $("#myListView li:contains('male')").hide();
}

};
```

Comment: How do you refresh the page?

Comment: Hi @omar I have this written at the end of a large code when user writes a new post and is send to the server, then back to the app. ` $( '#myPost' ).listview( "refresh" );`

Comment: You mean Ajax call? Or listview refresh?

Comment: @omar yes, Ajax call. so when you click the button to display the page containing the list, it refreshes. But then the given code is working but the code fires before the refresh of the page so is not longer working .

Comment: it's because ajax call is Asynchronous. It's probably didn't finish and updates it later. Put the ajax call in pagebeforeshow.

Answer (score 0):

It's because ajax call is Asynchronous. It's probably didn't finish and updates it later. Put the ajax call in pagebeforeshow.

name your page: `<div data-role="page" id="somename">`

do ajax call in page before show:

```
 $(document).on("pagebeforeshow","#somename",function(){
    var url='some server url, usually RESTful web apis'
        $.ajax({        
                 url:  url,           
                 error: function (){
                 alert('Network error has occurred. Please try again.');
                                 },
                 success: function(data){
                 alert('success:'+data);
                 } //end success

                }); //end ajax
        });
```

You can monitor when ajax call is finished.